# Get POST values by index in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

When I write this line

```
$this->input->post('question')
```

it returns me this

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(14) "eeeeeeeeeeeeee"
  [1]=>
  string(17) "fffffffffffffffff"
  [2]=>
  string(14) "gggggggggggggg"
}
```

I want index[1] value, like want to convert this:

```
$_POST["question"][$i]
```

into CI syntax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can save the entire array like this

```
$post_array = $this->input->post();
```

Then use `$post_array` in the same way as `$_POST`

or

```
$question = $this->input->post('question')
$question[$i]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = $this->input->post('some_data');
```

[Try this from CodeIgniter site](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html)